# coefficient plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to find a nice way to plot the linear model coefficient in python and I got the following:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = 'change ~ close_r + close_f + close_f1 + close_f2 + gender + age + country_of_citizenship + country_of_origin + religion +ethnicity'
reg_results = sm.ols(f, data=data).fit().summary()

sns.set(style="ticks") 
mpl.rc("figure", figsize=(10, 15))

sns.coefplot(f,data,intercept=False);
```

which produces the following ugly plot (you can't see the x axis labels).

[image]

How can I rotate the plot to make it vertical (i.e., the swap the y and x axis in order to see the labels)? and how can I add custom tick names for the coefficients (other than the default names from the dataframe)?

I am open to alternative solutions/type of plots as well.

Comment: would rotating the tick labels be an option? there are several questions/answers on SO that go over that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution M Waskow himself gave me when I raised the issue:

`ax = plt.gca()
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)`

See https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/576

Xaxis tick labels can be set with `plt.gca().set_xlabel(list_of_strings)`